# JTable: override CTRL+C behaviour

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable set on SINGLE_SELECTION mode, i.e. the user can only select one row at a time.
I am trying to override the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> KeyListener so that it will copy the whole table to the clipboard.

At the moment, I have added a KeyListener to the JTable itself in its constructor:

```
public MyTable(AbstractTableModel model) {
    super(model);
    getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    addKeyListener(new ExcelClipboardKeyAdapter(this));
}
```

The KeyListener looks like this:

```
public class ExcelClipboardKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

    private static final String LINE_BREAK = System.lineSeparator();
    private static final String CELL_BREAK = "\t";
    private static final Clipboard CLIPBOARD = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    private final JTable table;

    public ExcelClipboardKeyAdapter(JTable table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.isControlDown()) {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C) { // Copy                        
                copyToClipboard();
                System.out.println("here");
            }
        }
    }

    private void copyToClipboard() {
        int numCols = table.getColumnCount();
        int numRows = table.getRowCount();
        StringBuilder excelStr = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
                excelStr.append(escape(table.getValueAt(i, j)));
                if (j < numCols - 1) {
                    excelStr.append(CELL_BREAK);
                }
            }
            excelStr.append(LINE_BREAK);
        }

        StringSelection sel = new StringSelection(excelStr.toString());
        CLIPBOARD.setContents(sel, sel);
    }

    private String escape(Object cell) {
        return (cell == null? "" : cell.toString().replace(LINE_BREAK, " ").replace(CELL_BREAK, " "));
    }
}
```

However, when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the `keyreleased` method is not called and does not print "here". The content of the clipboard only contains the selected line.

Any ideas would be welcome.

**EDIT**

Actually it sometimes works a few times then it stops working and copies one row again... weird...

Comment: actually, just checked: the default already has a plaintextflavour with tabs separating the cells and line-breaks (that is "\n") separating the rows - so, do you really need the _system_ separator? Can't excel handle the single linebreak on import?

Comment: @kleopatra Having a look now. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @kleopatra Works like a charm, probably better than the KeyBindings way. Feel free to create an answer if you want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

moving my comment into an answer:

implement a custom TransferHandler which creates the "excel-transferable" and use that in the table (with dragEnabled == true) - the keybinding as appropriate for the target OS - then is automatically wired

Comment: It does override the CTRL+C behavior + enables drag and drop into Excel. Cool thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1) use `KeyBundings`, rather than `KeyListener`, because there isn't any issues with Focus and setFosusable

2) can you explain for why reason you needed to determine `SystemClipboard` this way, maybe there is/are another way(s)

Comment: Ok will have a look at keybindings. Not sure what you mean in your second question.

Comment: Using keybindings instead seems to have solved the problem. Thanks.